# Astra h 1.9 88kw 2006

Tags: electrical, opel, astra

I am having problems with Astra h 1.9 88kw 2006, it's constantly going in limp mode during driving, once I put it on diagnostics it's saying gas pedal, I change it and still have a problem, can anybody help.

Comment: I changed the pedal 4 times in 2 years, and it only solved the problem temporarily, now even after changing it the next day it started giving me greef

Comment: Have you checked the wiring to the gas pedal?

Comment: You mean from the pedal to the computer, that will be next step, it is very strange how it happenes it can come on 50 times in 1 hour and then nothing for few days as if I have Gremlins in the car

Comment: What is the code you get from the reader - usually more than "gas pedal". And when you have to fit 4 pedals it does tend to point to something else as the issue.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a grounding issue to the pedal, which when it's changed out it regains continuity, then over time, loses it again.

Comment: I am going to the electrician tomorrow and will ask him to check, will let you know, thanks a lot